# woocommerce checkout if statement

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create a select box on my client's woocommerce checkout page on Wordpress that asks where the customer heard about the site. I've got as far as creating it and am now trying to have a text box pop up when "other" is selected. So far, it's not happening.

Here's the code I have for the drop down and the text box at the moment:

```
/**
* Add how did you hear about us field to the checkout
**/
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'how_did_you_hear');

function how_did_you_hear( $checkout ) {

echo '<div id="how_did_you_hear">';

woocommerce_form_field( 'hear_about_us', array(
'type'          => 'select',
'class'         => array('how_did_you_hear_about_us form-row-wide'),
'label'         => __('How did you hear about us?'),
'required'      => true,
'onChange'      =>'howdidOnchange();',
'options'       => array(
'' => __('-- Choose an option --', 'woocommerce'),
'Google' => __('Google', 'woocommerce'),
'Facebook' => __('Facebook', 'woocommerce'),
'Twitter' => __('Twitter', 'woocommerce'),
'Mother & Baby Magazine' => __('Mother & Baby Magazine', 'woocommerce'),
'eBay' => __('eBay', 'woocommerce'),
'Count the Kicks' => __('Count the Kicks', 'woocommerce'),
'Other (please specify)' => __('Other (please specify)', 'woocommerce'))
), $checkout->get_value( 'hear_about_us' ));

echo '</div>';

}

/**
* Process the checkout
**/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'how_did_you_hear_process');

function how_did_you_hear_process() {
global $woocommerce;
}

/**
* Update the order meta with field value
**/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'how_did_you_hear_update_order_meta');

function how_did_you_hear_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
if ($_POST['hear_about_us']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'How did you hear about us?', esc_attr($_POST['hear_about_us']));
}

//Add text box if other is selected

if ($_POST['hear_about_us'] == 'Other (please specify)') {

add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'how_did_other');

function how_did_other( $checkout ) {

echo '<div id="how_did_other">';

woocommerce_form_field( 'other_please_specify', array(
'type'          => 'text',
'class'         => array('other-please-specify form-row-wide'),
'label'         => __('Other (please specify)'),
'placeholder'       => __('Enter something'),
), $checkout->get_value( 'other_please_specify' ));

echo '</div>';

}

/**
* Process the checkout
**/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'how_did_other_process');

function how_did_other_process() {
global $woocommerce;
}

/**
* Update the order meta with field value
**/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'how_did_other_update_order_meta');

function how_did_other_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
if ($_POST['other_please_specify']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Other (please specify)', esc_attr($_POST['other_please_specify']));
}
}
```

I've read a few ways to do this when it's not woocommerce, but I can't get that to work either, so this seemed like the best approach - although I could be wrong.

I've also noticed that in the code on the site, when the placeholder is selected, it shows as `<option value selected="selected">` but when I select the other options, that is still only shown on the placeholder, so I don't know if that has something to do with the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['hear_about_us']` will only be set after the checkout page has been submitted, and the `woocommerce_after_order_notes` hook runs when the checkout page is loaded. So you're adding `how_did_other` to the hook after it has already run.

The simplest way to do it is to include the other text box initially but hidden with `style="display:none;"`, and reveal it with javascript

```
var selectInput = $('.how_did_you_hear_about_us');
var otherInput = $('.other-please-specify');
selectInput.change(function() {
    if(selectInput.val()==='Other (please specify)') {
        otherInput.show();
    } else {
        otherInput.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I'm having a little trouble knowing where in my code to place it. I tried just putting it at the end of the section I posted up there, but I came up with a couple of errors and when I uploaded the file it told me I had a parse error because of an unexpected var. Do you know what I might be doing wrong there?

Thanks again for your help :)

Jess

Comment: the code in my answer is javascript, you can't include it with your php ;) add `style => "display:none;"` to you `woocommerce_form_field` and then include the js in your sites js file

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your help. I don't know what I'm doing wrong but adding style => "display:none;" doesn't seem to do anything. Also, because I'm using a child theme, I've tried dequeuing the original js file and enqueueing my own with your addition at the bottom, and that doesn't seem to be doing anything either. I'm also still getting an error on the last line of your code in my js file (checkout.js - I think this is the right one, but I'll be honest, I'm not 100% certain). Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated :) Jess

Comment: there was a missing bracket in my js sorry. It may be that `woocommerce_form_field` doesn't support `style`, best to just do it in the js with `otherInput.hide();` addit before the third line.

Comment: Thank you again for your response - I think it's getting there, but it's still not quite working. Basically I've managed to get the code into the right part of the javascript so that the text box is hidden, so I know it must be in the right place, but for some reason, when I select Other (please specify), it's not showing. I know I mentioned this before, but it's still doing the thing where in inspect element the code shows the first option (-- Choose an option --) as having value selected, and not any others. I'm not sure if that might have something to do with it :S